# Тырить - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Тырить, как известно, жаргонное или просторечное слово, значащее "воровать". Я порой употребляю его в шутку.

Было бы очень интересно узнать происхождение этого слова. Что-то мне подсказывает, что у него славянские корни, в отличие от многих жаргонов, но я могу и ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

"Славянское" обнаружено Далем в курском диалекте, вот скриншот нескольких словарных статеек, где можно проследить схожие корни:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашла интересное, но, увы, без штампа "Уплочено"...

> Цыганская этимология производящих основ была предложена А.П.
>   Баранниковым; согласно его мнению, ***тырить*** является
>   заимствованием из цыг. ***тэ тырдэс*** «тянуть, тащить, воровать».

А впрочем, почему без штампа? Вполне себе научное исследование:

[**РУССКИЕ АРГОТИЧЕСКИЕ ЭТИМОЛОГИИ**](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/dyachok-shapoval-88.htm#22)

> (Русская лексика в историческом развитии. - Новосибирск, 1988. - С.
>   52-60)